# Preventing horizontal scrolling after a certain width

Tags: html, css, image

I'm making a website with a large image at the top that extends past the far right of the page. The problem is that the browser keeps adding a horizontal scroll bar to allow the user to scroll to the end of this image but I don;t want it to do that.

Is there any way I can tell the browser to treat the image a bit like a background image or to simply stop scrolling after 940px?

http://www.electric-drumkit.com/404.php

There's an example of the page so you can get a better idea of what I mean.

Comment: You should use bigger images if you want the image to `"extend past the far right of the page"`. For instance, it [looks like this](http://i.imgur.com/mRBEu.jpg) for me, and I don't even have the browser at full size; not even close to it. Plenty of users have screens with a horizontal width larger than `940px`.

Comment: When I say page I mean the edges of the content. Usually the images are full images so you don't get that straight line break on the right hand side, but it looks like I'll have to tweak this one lol.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way to do it here is to:

- Add a new `div` (or other relevant HTML5 tag if you prefer): `<div id="wrapper">`, containing everything inside `body`.
- Move these rules from `body` to `#wrapper`:

  ```
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  ```
- Add this new CSS:

  ```
  body {
      min-width: 960px;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  ```
- Add this to get horizontal scrolling back when the window is less than `960px` wide:

  ```
  html {
      overflow: auto;
  }
  ```

Here's a [***live demo***](http://jsbin.com/azomi4) so you can quickly see if my answer will have the desired effect.

Tested in Firefox, Chrome, IE8.

Comment: position:relative for wrapper is not necessary though.

Answer (score 0):

Put the image into a div like this:

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

And in CSS you can write:

```
.image {background: url(http://www.electric-drumkit.com/_images/_feat/404.png) bottom right no-repeat; height: 314px;}
```

In this way, your div will render the image as a background, into a div, and i think there will be no scrolling.

Comment: Yeah I guess this works but there's a different image for every page and it would really bloat the code. It's a last resort option lol